# Passing Template Variable to Template Function in C++14

Tags: c++, templates, compiler-construction, lazy-evaluation, c++14

I'm writing a compiler that compiles to C++ and am having type issues with my C++ code. The language is meant to be lazy, so we have a lazy value wrapper, Chunk. Here is a part of it, along with the problematic code:

```
#include <functional>
#include <memory>

template<class T>
class Chunk
{
public:
    Chunk();
    Chunk(std::function<T()> f);
    T operator()();

    std::function<T()> f_;

private:
    std::shared_ptr<T> cache_;
};

template<class T>
T Chunk<T>::operator()()
{
    if(cache_ == nullptr)
        cache_ = std::make_shared<T>(f_());
    return *cache_;
}

template<class T, class F>
T operator*(Chunk<T> t1, Chunk<F> t2)
{
    return t1() * t2();
}

template<class T, class... Args>
T apply(Chunk<std::function<T(Args...)>> c, Args... as)
{
    return c()(as...);
}

template<class F>
auto toChunk(F f) -> Chunk<decltype(f())>
{
    return Chunk<decltype(f())>(f);
}

template<class T, class F>
struct ops
{
    static const auto multiply =
        toChunk([]() { return ops::multiply_; });

    static const auto multiply_(Chunk<T> x, Chunk<F> y) -> decltype(x * y)
    {
        return x * y;
    }
};

int main()
{
    Chunk<double> t = toChunk([]() { return 1.0; });
    Chunk<float> f = toChunk([]() { return 2.0f; });

    apply(ops::multiply, t, f);
    return 0;
}
```

I can't figure out a definition of `multiply` to make this work without getting a `used without template parameters` error. (There may be a second issue here because `multiply_` isn't a `std::function`, but the compiler breaks on the lack of template parameters first.)

I could write a lot of overloads for every pair of types, but this is just really ugly. I tried making multiply a template variable without a template class, and even though I'm using C++14, got `cannot resolve address of overloaded function` at `multiply_` with this alternative definition:

```
template<class T, class F>
auto multiply_(Chunk<T> x, Chunk<F> y) -> decltype(x * y)
{
    return x * y;
}
template<class T, class F>
Chunk<decltype(multiply_)> multiply = toChunk([]() { return multiply_; });
```

Of course I then changed `ops::multiply` to simply `multiply`. Any suggestions to overcome this?

Comment: You forgot the most important part: Show us the `multiply` that you wrote. Or better yet: An SSCCE.

Comment: Did you try `apply<decltype(multiply)>(multiply, t, f)`? It's not very clear what the issue is, try posting an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Made the MCVE! Generating your suggestion would be tricky, and doesn't get past the errors with either of my multiply definitions unfortunately.

Comment: It's unclear what you want to do. `multiply_` is a function template, you can't just return it - it's not a thing. You'd have to return `multiply_<T,F>`.

Comment: @Barry To be precise, `mutliply_` is a function inside a class template, so it decays to function pointer.

Answer (score 2):

`ops` is a name of a class template. To refer to members of a class template outside of its definition you need to specify the template arguments.

If you fix this error though, there are going to be more.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using an entirely different solution. I overloaded `apply` by adding this second definition:

```
template<class F, class... Args>
auto apply(F f, Args... as) -> decltype(f(as...))
{
    return f(as...);
}
```

And rewrote multiply as simply:

```
auto multiply = [](auto x, auto y) { return x * y; };
```

So our library functions will not be in the lazy wrappers, while user-defined functions (which can't be templates in our language) will.

Comment: Why `-> decltype(f(as...))`?  Why no forwarding? (two distinct questions)